# How to separate C macros (#define) onto .h and .c file

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have following code from CUDA by example book:

```
static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                     const char *file,
                     int line ) {
if (err != cudaSuccess) {
    printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),file, line );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))


#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                        printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}
```

I want separate it into two files .h and .c like this:

```
#pragma once

#define HANDLE_ERROR
#define HANDLE_NULL

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line );
```

but I don't know how to separate macros HANDLE_EROOR?

Comment: Macros cannot be separated into declaration and definition. They are not functions but text substitutions.

Comment: Because HANDLE_ERROR uses HandleError function is there another way to separate in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only split the definition of `HandleError` function, but this requires to modify its linkage to external (the static functions have internal linkage and are limited to the file scope):

#### `book.h:`

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                            printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                    __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}

extern void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line );
```

#### `book.c:`

```
#include "book.h"

void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
                file, line );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

There isn't much sense to move explicitely `HANDLE_ERROR` and `HANDLE_NULL` macros into `.c` file as they will be outside of public view, making them "dead" (as they are not used there).

In general macros are not subject to *scope* nor *linkage* in the ordinary sense of the C language. These are just replaceable tokens, that are visible unless end-of-file is encountered, but may be also revoked by the `#undef` directive.

Answer (score 3):

As macros are instructions to the pre-processor how to perform text substitution, they cannot be separated into something that looks like a macro declaration and a macro definition, like a function. They are not functions.

The entire macro should preferrably go into the h-file.

Comment: But it returns error in this case: function "HandleError" was referenced but not defined